# Failure when trying to read saved data from Documents directory after relaunch

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I've read some answers for similar questions and every time the problem was in saving absolute path instead of saving just file name and recreating url every time. I've tried to follow examples of code that I saw in these answers, but result was the same : "Could not read from file because there is no such file or directory". I messed up somewhere for sure, and some help would be appreciated 
Writing:

```
let dir = FileManager.default
         .urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
let accountDir = dir.appendingPathComponent("\(self.getHexString(str: self.account))", isDirectory: true)
let imageUrl = accountDir.appendingPathComponent("\(self.path.rawValue)")

if let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
        FileManager().createFile(atPath: imageUrl.path, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)
    }
```

Reading:

```
let dir = FileManager.default
        .urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let accountDir = dir.appendingPathComponent("\(self.getHexString(str: self.account))", isDirectory: true)
    let imageUrl = accountDir.appendingPathComponent("\(self.path.rawValue)")

   let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: imageUrl)
```

Comment: How you are getting the hexstring?? while writing and reading hexString created is same?

Comment: I've just written the method that converts string to hexString. String to be converted is the same for each file, so yeah, its the same for reading and writing

Comment: The question cannot be answered without knowing what `getHexString` and `path.rawValue` is. `print` the URLs and compare them. By the way, writing the data with `try imageData.write(to:  imageUrl)` is much more convenient.

Comment: If you run this in simulator, are you able to actually see the image being saved at the intended location in documents directory?

Comment: I went to this location : `Estatico/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A0C7F39A-405E-499E-BECA-441FA862BFB5/data/Containers/Data/Application/652BDE09-2410-43B8-AE3D-E31E01009A16/Documents/6f6c653231406d61696c696e61746f722e636f6d/dpurgh4infnubjhcost7fvjkdwnvkcedflpqdxlxsc5nlsib4diraweq` and didnt find any picture. This is hexString : `6f6c653231406d61696c696e61746f722e636f6d`, its equal for every picture, its a path.rawValue: `dpurgh4infnubjhcost7fvjkdwnvkcedflpqdxlxsc5nlsib4diraweq`, its a unique for every picture

Comment: For deugging, forget your path, and try saving the image with a default name (like testimage.jpg) directly into documents directory and reading it with the same name. If it works, the issue is with your path generation, if not you can look into image creation code etc. and update your question accordingly.

Comment: I've managed to solve this problem. I was trying to write file in a directory, that doesn't exist. Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought that directory where I wanted to store my images is created automatically when I append it to path and flag `isDirectory: true`, but it doesn't. So the correct code is :

```
let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    let accountDir = dir.appendingPathComponent("\(self.getHexString(str: self.account))", isDirectory: true)

    let isDirectoryExists = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: accountDir.path)
    if !isDirectoryExists {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: accountDir.path, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
        } catch(let error) {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    let imageUrl = accountDir.appendingPathComponent("\(self.path.rawValue)")
    if let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
        FileManager().createFile(atPath: imageUrl.path, contents: imageData, attributes: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be two reasons:

1. It is not creating the path properly. 
   Try changing `image.path` to `image.absoluteString`
2. I think it is just creating the file but not writing anything in that

   Try the below code after createfile:

   `let file = try FileHandle(forUpdating: imageUrl)
   file.seekToEndOfFile()
   file.write(data: imageData)
   file.closeFile()`

Comment: I found out that it doesn't even create file. Trying to figure out why

Comment: No, `contents: imageData` is the data to be written.

Comment: @estatico instead of `imageUrl.path` try to use `imageUrl.absoluteString`

Comment: @Shruti when I was researching for the answer, I saw that it should be exactly `imageUrl.path`

Comment: @estatico but path is going to return you something like  `/Users/Desktop` and absolute string will return `file:///Users/Desktop/`